# Navbar brand issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

There is space on the left of my brand and I dont know how to get rid of it. Setting the navbar-brand  padding to 0px takes away only half of the space. I also cannot figure out how to get the links on the right to center with the brand. Suggestions?

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  float:none !important;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>

        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="col-lg-12 navigation">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <span><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" width="80" height="80" alt=""></span>Logo
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-collapse pull-right collapse" id="navbar-collapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  Rest of page content
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @jaydeeppatel done

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you working with 3 or 4 ??

Comment: And it's better replacing container with container-fluid  right?? your navbar expands to the entire width of the screen then. Once google the difference between container and container-fluid

Comment: just commented out that `styles/styles.css`, because it was a `404`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin for `.container` to zero.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  float: none !important;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="col-lg-12 navigation">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <span><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x80" width="80" height="80" alt=""></span>Logo
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-collapse pull-right collapse" id="navbar-collapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  Rest of page content
</div>
```

Comment: it does replace with all the containers right ?? even if he has different containers used. Is there any issue using container-fluid ??

Comment: Using container-fluid shouldn't be an issue. If there are more container classes and they need to have different margins, it's best to add a class to this one and add it to the CSS. Something like .container.zeromargin

Answer (score 0):

You should be use this simple trick.

```
button.navbar-toggle.collapsed {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    float: left;
}
.col-lg-12.navigation {
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarification.

```css
.navbar {
background-color: cyan;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand {
float:none !important;
padding: 0px;
}

button.navbar-toggle.collapsed{
height: 0;
width: 0;
padding: 0;
border-width: 0;
font-size: 0;
float: left;
}
.col-lg-12.navigation {
padding: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{padding: 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>

        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="col-lg-12 navigation">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <span><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" width="80" height="80" alt=""></span>Logo
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-collapse pull-right collapse" id="navbar-collapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is coming from bootstrap.css - and it's an easy fix:

```
div.col-lg-12.navigation {padding-left: 0;}
a.navbar-brand {padding: 0;}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, do you know how I can get the links to centre though?

Comment: @Oblivion maybe consider changing the order of DOM nodes, because the text appears to be before/underneath the logo, which is adding towards such alignment issues; I mean, even if the logo is in place alike that, the headline would need some visual padding to the left.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how would changing the order of the DOM nodes allow the links on the right to be positioned vertically centre to the brand?

Comment: @Oblivion you'd have to remove class `pull-right` from node `navbar-toggle collapsed` then `.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {padding-left: 38px;}` (or possibly 15px less)...and what I mean is, that the headline should come after the logo and not before it, which would make aligning it easier.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by headline, what i'm wondering is why .
navbar-nav > li a {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

isnt working?